# Южно-Африканская Республика vs. Центральноевропейское время

Tags: правописание, орфография

Could anybody explain to me why Южно-Африканская Республика is written with a hyphen? I thought a hyphen was a sort of replacement for и, meaning that the two parts of the word are of equal relation to the following noun. For example сине-красный купальник. However, in Южно-Африканская Республика the word южный relates to Africa rather than to Republic, just as in центральноевропейское время central defines the part of Europe, not time. Why is then spelling different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Южно-Африканская* and *центральноевропейское* are adjectives. There are [the rules](http://therules.ru/hyphen-adjectives/) that govern when adjectives are written with a hyphen.

*Центральноевропейское* is written in one according to the rule of 80.3, because it is formed by the base *Центральная Европа* and used as a term.

*Южно-Африканская Республика* is written with a hyphen according to the rule of 81.4, because it is a geographic name starts with *южно-*.

I don't know why this rule exists, perhaps it is one of many exceptions. There is common mistake when [Южноафриканская Республика](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%AE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%22) is used.

Other examples: южноафриканское время, южноафриканская лисица, Южно-Американская плита.

---

Слова *Южно-Африканская* и *центральноевропейское* - это прилагательные. [Вот правила](http://therules.ru/hyphen-adjectives/), когда прилагательные пишутся через дефис.

По правилу 80.3 слово *центральноевропейское* пишется слитно, так как образовано от двух слов *Центральная Европа* и используется как термин.

По правилу 81.4 *Южно-Африканская Республика* пишется через дефис, так как это географическое название, начинающееся с *южно-*.

Почему появилось такое правило сказать не могу, видимо это одно из многих исключений. Так что часто встречается ошибка, когда пишут [Южноафриканская Республика](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%AE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%22).

Другие примеры применения этих правил: южноафриканское время, южноафриканская лисица, Южно-Американская плита.

Comment: The link for rules you give - it looks like the content there is copied from some book and put on the web. For credibility of source would be nice to know what book it was.

Comment: These rules are from "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" that was [accepted in 1956](http://orthowiki.kalan.cc/wiki/Реформа_1956_года). You can also find it [here](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/).

Answer (score 7):

*Южно-Африканская* (as in *Южно-Африканская Республика*) is a part of a proper name. Both parts should start with a capital and be separated with a hyphen.

*Центральноевропейское* (as in *центральноевропейское время*) is not a part of a proper name, and hence is written as a one word.

Compare:

> - Ботсвана — небольшая южноафриканская республика, граничащая с Южно-Африканской Республикой.
> - Центрально-Европейский университет находится в Будапеште. Занятия в нём начинаются в 8 часов по центральноевропейскому времени.

Comment: The rules only list  восточно-, западно-, северно- и северо-, южно- and юго- as being written with hyphen in geographic names. Why do you think the same rule applies to центрально- and to non-geographic proper names?

Comment: Take for instance the 
Центральноевропейский нефтегазоносный бассейн
( http://megabook.ru/article/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD ) It seems the Центрально-Европейский Университет is just an incorrect calque from English.

Comment: @Anixx You may disagree with how they called «Центрально-Европейский Университет» in Russian, but to call it incorrect is… incorrect in itself. It is analogous to «Майкрософт» (rather than «Микрософт»), being a propper noun.

Comment: @Volodya in that case it should not be used as an example and argument for the proof.